# php use filter_var_array to strip anything but a-z

Tags: php, arrays, sanitize

I am trying to remove all characters from my array values except for the a-z characters using the [filter_var_array](http://www.php.net/filter_var_array) function.

I tried applying multiple [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) but unfortunatly none of them did the trick for me, is there any other way to do this using this function or am I forced to use something like regex in a foreach loop to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have tried the `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH` filter?

Comment: Suggest stating more explicitly whether you want case sensitivity or not.  If so, mention that uppercase characters should be removed.  If not (this is what I suspect you want), then say that a-z and A-Z should be kept.  Also assuming you want to strip exotics &auml; &egrave; &otilde;.  If you do want to strip them, then I suggest no change is necessary, but just checking.  Also, is it a disappointment most of the answers don't use filters as you asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace()` already works quite naturally on an array.  This removes all non-alphas from an array of strings:

```
$array = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $array);
```

Example:

```
$a = array('1111A55b999c0000','111111def9999999','0000000g88888hi8888888');
$a = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $a);
assert($a == array('Abc','def','ghi'));
```

I'm guessing you may want case-insensitivity.  If you truly want to strip out uppercase letters as well, just remove the `i`.

Comment: True, but I am guessing the + makes it *slightly* more efficient, by removing **chunks** of non-alphas, instead of individual **characters**.  But only a profiler could tell for sure.  (Using an * however risks a rift in the spacetime continuum.)

Comment: Thats interesting. I would assume it should be faster _without_ `+`, because it would reduce the pattern matching itself to a single step. I fear the right answer is "there is no difference internally (except the execution paths)"  :D

Comment: Good point, @KingCrunch.  The faster way may even be data-dependent:  Lots of consecutive non-alpha?  Maybe faster with plus.  Lots of all-alpha already?  Maybe faster with a simpler pattern.  But because my code is so long and cumbersome, maybe removing the + would improve it.  You know, for brevity sake.

Comment: Okay removed the `+` for aesthetic reasons.  And uncertainty whether `'/[^a-z]/i'` or `'/[^a-z]+/i'` is faster

Answer (score 2):

```
$f = function ($string) { return preg_replace('~[^a-z]~i', '', $string); };
$myValues = array_map($f, $myValues);
```

Comment: Do anonymous function still have problems with "garbage collection" in PHP?

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich What are you talking about? Beside that this highly depends on the version you use, you as a user should never need to take care about GC, because the builtin GC is quite good at his job :)

Comment: I remember GC is mostly reference count mechanism in PHP.. and yes - anonymous functions did have memory leaks.. just was wondering what is the current status (e.g. with code in production using anonymous functions)

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich Every GC bases on counting references. Thats the way to find out, whether or a reference is still used ;) Must say, that I didn't heared, that PHP has special problems with closures and GC, before. I'd say they are either fixed, or only important in some edge cases :) Closures are widely used in the meantime, thus I guess they wouldn't get that popular, if they breaks every second application :D

Comment: Respectfully request @xorinzor look at my other answer - the one with a single `preg_replace()` call.  Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `array_map` and a regex, personally.

```
     $array = Array("abc123", "123jkl", "abc123def");
     $array = array_map("preg_replace", 
                         array_fill(0, count($array), '/[^a-z]*/'), 
                         array_fill(0, count($array), ''),
                         $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

## scanning == regexps

As with other answers this one is again based on mastering [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which is essentially *THE* basic character scanning (and parsing) technique all those validators are built upon. The idea about validators/filters is to define/guess/cover as many reasonable [classes of strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) (regexps) as possible. (Plus there is an optimization speed up for trivial classes like [0-9]* or [a-z]* -  no need to go via standard *perl-compatible*)

## filter_var_array and callbacks

As a quick remark: indeed, things like **FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP** did not work for me either...

**filter_var_array** & co. is relatively new practice, but  if you *must* then fallback to whatever custom  **FILTER_CALLBACK** works in the [following](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) form:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

function handle($value) {
    return preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $value);
}

$data = array(
    'testfield'    => array('22', 'foo', 'bar', '42'),
);

$args = array(
    'testfield'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                            'options'   => 'handle'
        ),
    );

$result = filter_var_array($data, $args);

var_dump($result);
```

and produces

```
array(1) {
  ["testfield"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps no better than foreach, but it is an "other way":

```
array_walk($a, function(&$e) {
    $e = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $e);
});
```

(Requires PHP 5.3 if you use this anonymous function syntax, also called a "closure".)

Comment: Anonymous functions and closures are two different things. Just said :) (In fact closures are a subset of anonymous functions).

Comment: Really  @KingCrunch?  In the PHP docs for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and the [Closure class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) I haven't seen the distinction yet.  Do you?

Comment: The distinction comes not from PHP: An anonymous function is a function without name. A closure is an anonymous function with additional references to non-local variables. Strictly spoken `function foo() {}` is a anonymous function, `function foo() use ($bar) {}` is a closure. In PHP the difference doesn't matter at all, so the distinction is unimportant, but other languages uses the fact, that functions (not closures) shouldn't have any side-effect to parallize them.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone **closure != closure class**. Later is just an implementation. There were numerous PCE implementation attempts with respective blogs before PHP5.2, I would guess *closure class* is just a consequence of that activity.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich I didn't talked about implementation details, but about the concepts. This is not even related to PHP only ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch ultimately closure is an algebraic concept in all functional programming languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics) . Closure is by no means a function.. :-) you are completely right

Comment: Would love to have a long talk over lunch with you, KingCrunch and @YauhenYakimovich.  Might be hard to get to closure on any topic, but it'd be fun.